# Assistant editor New xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

When I make another view controller and click it the assistant coding changes and will not let me edit. check out the picture please help thanks [Click below to see a picture.] https://ibb.co/nDm0qjM

First view controller assistant. This is what I need https://ibb.co/cCMQ1xG

Comment: That's because it's showing some other code, notice the `< 2 >` in the upper right corner. Click on either <,> to show your vc code

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the auto-assist for `UIViewController` i.e `UIViewController.h` which is the template class of your storyboard instance. Until you change the class of your View Controller to the actual class you'll see this.

Or you can click on that middle widget to change the display mode in the assistant pane.

[image]

p.s. - COMMAND-SHIFT-4 will let you take screenshots of part of the screen.

Comment: Got it thanks. How can I fix this? Check pic.   https://ibb.co/cFFHCmn

Comment: Your class is called `ViewController`, it should be available. If you start typing it should complete.